# Android Floating Action Button not resetting position

Tags: android, floating-action-button

Using the 23.3.0 version of the support libraries and testing on Android M. And having issues with a FAB repositioning itself after a Snackbar is shown.

The fab correctly moves up when a Snackbar is shown, however it does not move down when the Snackbar dismisses itself.

Code:

```
Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, R.string.msg_add_team,     Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Also tried to use the callback functionality of the Snackbar to force the position back on dismiss, this breaks subsequent displays of the Snackbar as it will no longer move the fab out of the way.

Code for callback:

```
@Override
public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
    super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);                       
    newGameFab.setTranslationY(0); 
}
```

Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/upcoming_game_list"
/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/new_game"
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your View containing floating action button with a `CoordinatorLayout` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/upcoming_game_list"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/new_game"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The provided layout is part of a fragment that is included inside of a different layout that has the CoordinatorLayout.